# App Store iOS Submission Issue - Icon Size?

Tags: ios, app-store

I received the following message after submitting an update.

> If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must
>   include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels and
>   120x120 pixels.

Why 120x120? Retina resolution is 114x114 which I have. Is it because of iOS 7? iOS 7 isn't even out yet though.

Comment: I don't see any 120x120 icon sizes mentioned in either the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) or [Technical Q&A QA1686](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html).

Comment: you can use this application to create all icons for an ios application https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 7 iPhone Retina icon is looking like it is going to be 120px by 120px.

**iOS 7 iPhone:**

```
Standard: 60px x 60px
Retina: 120px x 120px
```

**iOS 7 iPad:**

```
Standard: 76px x 76px 
Retina: 152px x 152px
```

Looks like Apple decided to start enforcing the requirements a bit early, which does not surprise me in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem happened here bud I did not have an option to continue. It gives me the red dot and "Invalid Binary". However i've managed to fix that issue after 1 day trial and error.

The sollution is:

Rename the icon files in a way that they do not contain @2x suffix!

Before:

```
icon.png
icon@2x.png
icon~iPad.png
icon~iPad@2x.png
```

Now:

```
icon.png
icon_iphone4.png
icon_ipad.png
icon_ipad3.png
```

I also added "CFBundleIcons" key to the Info.plist file and added the "CFBundleIconFiles" array under the Primary icon key.

Comment: I stuck with this issue for 2 weeks.. When first I saw this answer I ignore it.. But it fix my issue now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any necessary adjustments for the standard size, but there are adjustments needed for retina. This is a direct screenshot from Xcode 5.

[image: icon sizes]

It's kind of bogus, because you're right iOS7 isn't out, so they shouldn't force you. I submitted my app during the keynote with no trouble, but made the conversion quickly and am actually resubmitting now for iOS 7. It's weird that you got that message and I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 isn't out yet as stated, but it's prudent for Apple to start enforcing the soon-to-be requirements as early as is feasible. You will notice that apps with a 57x57 or 114x114 icon will occasionally display entirely wrong on an iOS 7 device.

Implementing the new guidelines early - bearing in mind we should be getting a GM imminently - ensures that a lot of these problems will be eliminated.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you shouldn't use the XCode beta version to submit your apps but remain on using your old XCode non-beta to submit your apps!

Here I didn't had any problems whatsoever regarding the old @2x suffix and the sizes.